# Google Analytics for Email Tracking when using Universal Links on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, ios-universal-links

I would like to track button clicks in emails using Google Analytics. Let's say I would like the button to have a Universal Link, which when clicked, will open an iOS app directly with no browser redirect. (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

However, if my URL is a Universal Link, i.e. **www.xyzxyz.com/openApp**?campaign=promo&source=email, and an email recipient clicks the link from their iPhone with the installed app, no call is made to the server, and therefore the click is not tracked.

Has anyone experienced a way of tracking Universal Link clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Universal Links are handled on the frontend by the device without ever interacting with a server if the app is installed. The AASA file is stored on the device at install and allows the device to check whether the link can open the app before passing the link onto safari. If the app is not installed and the link is passed onto Safari then the Google analytics tags will be processed. The only way to accomplish this is to send the GA request from the app if you register that a Universal Link was clicked.

I recommend looking into a deep linking service like [Branch](http://branch.io). They have a [Google analytics data integration](https://docs.branch.io/pages/integrations/google-analytics/) that will handle all of this tracking for you.